# How to set CSS class in AngularJS directive and default if none set?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a custom directive which creates an "upload button". It has the bootstrap button CSS applied to it like so:

```
<div class="btn btn-primary btn-upload" ng-click="openModal()">
  <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload
</div>
```

How do I override the CSS classes and default to `btn btn-primary btn-upload` if no override specified? The goal is to reuse the same directive throughout the app but in some places it's a button and other places it's just a basic un-styled link.

My directive looks like so:

```
'use strict';

    angular.module('documents').directive('documentUpload', ['$timeout', '$translate', '$q', '$docs',
      function ($timeout, $translate, $q, $docs) {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
            text: '@',
            refId: '@',
            refType: '@',
            documents: '='
          },
          templateUrl: 'modules/documents/views/directives/document-upload.html',
          controller: function ($scope, $element) {

            // override css somewhere here?

            $scope.openModal = function() {

              $docs
                .openModal({ 
                  documents: $scope.documents,
                  refId: $scope.refId,
                  refType: $scope.refType
                })
                .result.then(function (result) {
                  // TODO 
                });

            };

          }
        };
      }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
<div class="{{ btnClass || 'btn btn-primary btn-upload'}}" ng-click="openModal()">
  <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload
</div>
```

And then the directive:

```
angular.module('documents').directive('documentUpload', ['$timeout', '$translate', '$q', '$docs',
  function ($timeout, $translate, $q, $docs) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        text: '@',
        refId: '@',
        refType: '@',
        documents: '=',
        btnClass: '=' //** new attribute here
      },
      templateUrl: 'modules/documents/views/directives/document-upload.html',
      controller: function ($scope, $element) {

        $scope.openModal = function() {

          $docs
            .openModal({ 
              documents: $scope.documents,
              refId: $scope.refId,
              refType: $scope.refType
            })
            .result.then(function (result) {
              // TODO 
            });

        };

      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Here's a stripped down example: http://jsbin.com/qosiquteli/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I thought this was the proper way as well, I tried it and always defaults to `btn btn-primary btn-upload` maybe I am missing something? Do I need to do more with the directive to set the class? `<document-upload ref-id="{{ ref._id }}" ref-type="MyRefType" btn-class="override" documents="docs"></document-upload>`

Comment: If you pass the btnClass attribute a string literal, be sure to wrap it in single-quotes, like so: `<div document-upload btn-class="'btn-sec'"></div>`. Otherwise, angular is looking for a property on the $scope object of that name. If it finds nothing, it fails silently. Does that solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the div class if class attribute defined:

```
 angular.module('documents').directive('documentUpload', ['$timeout', '$translate', '$q', '$docs',
      function ($timeout, $translate, $q, $docs) {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
            text: '@',
            refId: '@',
            refType: '@',
            documents: '='
          },
          templateUrl: 'modules/documents/views/directives/document-upload.html',
          link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs){
             if (iAttrs.class) {
                iElement.find("div").first().attr("class", iAttrs.class);
             }
           },
          controller: function ($scope, $element) {

            // override css somewhere here?

            $scope.openModal = function() {

              $docs
                .openModal({ 
                  documents: $scope.documents,
                  refId: $scope.refId,
                  refType: $scope.refType
                })
                .result.then(function (result) {
                  // TODO 
                });

            };

          }
        };
      }
    ]);
```